# Redis keys security for multiple users

Tags: wordpress, redis

I have installed a  redis server, and i have multiple clients using Mysql for their WordPress sites. I have configured redis and its working fine. Now I want some type of security like one of my client can switch to other redis databases and can list all keys of all clients, i want to prevent it.

```
root@rest: redis-cli
x.x.x.x:6379> KEYS *

 1) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:terms:last_changed"
 2) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:terms:get_terms-8fe839c888a1f5dc584d66e75abe752b-0.12728000 1606912094"
 3) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:post_tag_relationships:1"
 4) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:post_meta:3"
 5) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:comment:last_changed"
 6) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:site-transient:theme_roots"
 7) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:posts:last_changed"
 8) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:redis-cache:metrics"
 9) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:comment:1"
10) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:site-transient:update_plugins"
11) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:options:alloptions"
12) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:posts:3"
13) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:user_meta:1"
14) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:post_meta:1"
15) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:users:1"
16) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:terms:1"
17) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:comment:1"
18) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:terms:1"
19) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:term_meta:1"
20) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:options:can_compress_scripts"
21) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:post_meta:3"
22) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:site-transient:update_core"
23) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:options:notoptions"
24) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:post_format_relationships:1"
25) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:terms:get_terms-6a7e5a5984989e684e977a4689029aeb-0.03989400 1606912075"
26) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:posts:1"
27) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:default:is_blog_installed"
28) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:comment:last_changed"
29) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:site-options:1-notoptions"
30) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:comment:get_comments-a83484ce4441a2d87a90609f886c4a28-0.14044500 1606912094"
31) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:comment_meta:1"
32) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:default:is_blog_installed"
33) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:posts:wp_get_archives-10425ab9cab74a55e05d28aee32fbd7a-0.05052900 1606912075"
34) "s-dev-ortizfurt.:terms:get_terms-fa6fef0e8f76461d0c23f81cca942240-0.03989400 1606912075"
35) "s-dev-mayerhaven.:posts:3"
```

I have already tried by creating separate DB and assigned to each client.

Is there a way to stop users from listing keys or creating users for each database like in mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Redis 6.0, it support [ACL](https://redis.io/topics/acl). In your case, you can create users for different clients, and limit the access control for each user.

For example, you can create a user (with password: *passwd*) named **ortizfurt**, who only has access to keys starting with *s-dev-ortizfurt.:*

```
ACL SETUSER ortizfurt on >passwd ~s-dev-ortizfurt.:* +@all
```

Comment: i have now  redis 6 on  server. i have set a specific DB for a specific user  which is s-dev-lake-anitax 
current keys are 

`"s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:default:is_blog_installed"
"s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:post_meta:1"`
and ran command ACL SETUSER s-dev-lake-anitax on >123 ~s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:* +@all
**output:**
(error) ERR Error in ACL SETUSER modifier '~s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:*': Adding a pattern after the * pattern (or the 'allkeys' flag) is not valid and does not have any effect. Try 'resetkeys' to start with an empty list of patterns

Comment: It seem that you already add a rule for all keys, e.g. `ACL SETUSER user on >pass ~* +@all`, or `ACL SETUSER user on >pass allkeys +@all`. In this case, as the error message says, you cannot add another rule, since this all keys rule already covers other rules.

Comment: thanks for your help @for_stack i have fixed my acl now and set it  new acl with new user and password,
`acl setuser alex resetkeys ~secret ~s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:*`
current acl is showing now in acl list. Now i have connected to redis as a default user. how can i connect to redis as alex user

`x.x.x.x:6379> acl whoami
*"default"*`

Comment: AUTH alex secret

Comment: I totally support @for_stack's answer, but another way (much more secure, somewhat more admin-intensive) is to have a dedicated (Redis) instance per user. This may make less sense in small deployments, but given that the Redis server overhead is almost 0 it provides a lucrative path towards multi-tenancy.

Comment: @for_stack i have now created a rule 

`ACL SETUSER wajahat  on >123 ~secret ~dev-phyllislandKTjD:* +@all`

but it its getting all keys on all dbs
`32) "dev-phyllislandKTjD:site-transient:update_core"
33) "dev-phyllislandKTjD:options:notoptions"
34) "dev-phyllislandKTjD:term_meta:1"
35) "dev-phyllislandKTjD:category_relationships:1"
36) "dev-phyllislandKTjD:site-options:1-notoptions"

s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:default:is_blog_installed"
35) "s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:posts:1"
36) "s-dev-lake-anitaxkGd:user_meta:1"`

Comment: @for_stack i can easily select other DBs and get all keys of other dbs

Comment: @ItamarHaber thanks for your suggestion but simple ACL rules are not working. I have set ACL rule to **ACL SETUSER alex on >123 ~apple:* +@all**
but i can see all the keys with other prefixes in the db.
`127.0.0.1:6379[190]> KEYS *
"grape:green"
"apple:red"
127.0.0.1:6379[190]> ACL WHOAMI
"alex"`

Comment: @wajahat021 First of all, you should not use `KEYS` command, since it's a slow command, and might block Redis. You configure ACL with a key pattern, while KEYS command does not have a key as argument, so I think Redis cannot apply your rule to KEYS command.

Answer (score 2):

As per to the documentation, [here](https://redis.io/topics/security) redis does provide basic authentication mechanism,

Exact snippet from the documentation

> While Redis does not try to implement Access Control, it provides a
> tiny layer of authentication that is optionally turned on editing the
> redis.conf file.
>
> When the authorization layer is enabled, Redis will refuse any query
> by unauthenticated clients. A client can authenticate itself by
> sending the AUTH command followed by the password.

Please note, the password will be in plain-text in redis.conf file and is subjected to be viewed by unauthorized parties if they have access to it.

Additionally redis does provide a mechanism to rename or disable specific command, Exact snippet from the same document above ,

> it is possible to disable commands in Redis or to rename them into an
> unguessable name, so that normal clients are limited to a specified
> set of commands.

Here are some high-level pointers on how to secure a redis deployment

- Bind redis to localhost
- Configure AUTH by enabling requirepass in redis.conf
- Rename or disable dangerous commands